# c++ code won't compile with GCC because of typeid().raw_name() - how can I fix this?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

The following code compiles fine on Windows with Visual Studio:

```
class_handle(base *ptr) : ptr_m(ptr), name_m(typeid(base).raw_name()) { signature_m = CLASS_HANDLE_SIGNATURE; }
```

If I try to compile the same code on Linux I get:

```
error: ‘const class std::type_info’ has no member named ‘raw_name’
```

as far as I understand, `raw_name` is a Microsoft [specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70ky2y6k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) implementation. How do I have to change my code so it compiles both on Windows and Linux systems?

**EDIT1** I prefer to not modify the original code, I just need a workaround to compile with gcc. Is that possible?

**EDIT2** will `#define raw_name name` do the trick?

Comment: Is switching to `name()` ok?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I prefer to not modify the original code. any workarounds?

Comment: @memyself No clean, standard conforming workaround. (You could re-`#define` `raw_name` but doing so will send you to a special hell). Furthermore, there’s no need to ever use `raw_name` so I’d simply completely ban it from the code base.

Comment: @KonradRudolph so I shouldn't do `#define raw_name name`?

Comment: @memyself I’d only do it if I could strictly limit its scope to this one code location (by `#undef`ing it directly after including that code) and even then only if there’s a compelling reason not to modify the original code (yes, there *are* reasons for not doing that, I know).

Comment: @111 `.name` will *not* give you a unique anything. The unique identifier of a type is not the name but its typeinfo instance, which is why those are comparable in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write these:

```
// for variables:
template<typename T>
char const* GetRawName( T unused ) { ... }
// for types:
template<typename T>
char const* GetRawName() { ... }
```

with different implementation on Windows and not-on-Windows using an `#ifdef` block on a token you know to be defined in the microsoft compiler, but not in your other compiler.  This isolates the preprocessing differences between MS and non-MS compiled versions to an isolated file.

This does require a minimal amount of change to the original code, but does so in a way that will still compile on the microsoft compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably safer to `#define typeid`:

```
class compat_typeinfo {
  const std::type_info &ti;
public:
  explicit compat_typeinfo(const std::type_info &ti): ti(ti) {}
  const char *name() const { return ti.name(); }
  const char *raw_name() const { return ti.name(); }
};
compat_typeinfo compat_typeid(const std::type_info &ti) {
  return compat_typeinfo(ti);
}
#define typeid(x) compat_typeid(typeid(x))
```

Of course, this is illegal by 17.6.4.3.1p2 (*A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names lexically identical to keywords [...]*) but it's reasonably likely to work and requires minimal modification elsewhere.

Comment: Safer, maybe. But invalid (you aren’t allowed to redefine keywords words).

Comment: `.name()` returns the demangled name, `.raw_name()` returns the mangled name.

Answer (score 0):

GCC doesn't define `raw_name` but does include mangling/demangling in `cxxabi.h`. You can see an example of it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
//...
std::bad_exception  e;
realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(e.what(), 0, 0, &status);
std::cout << e.what() << "\t=> " << realname << "\t: " << status << '\n';
free(realname);
```